# Как задать стиль определенным ссылкам, не имеющим класса?

Tags: css3, css

Естественно CSS3. Заранее спасибо

```
a {
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
a {
    color: #0196e3;
    opacity: 0.8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #6dc23a;
    opacity: 0.8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Читать про селекторы.Они помогут получить доступ к элементам на вашей странице.

Comment: Т.е. у меня код на css3 с анимацией, а то это все дело ко всему липнет и даже к тем, что имеет класс, и получается неразбериха.

Comment: Можете показать кусок кода, куда нужно навешать стиль?

Comment: Вообщем ссылки ввида <a href="t2.html">qwe</a> или <a href="http://htmlbook.ru/">qwe</a>

Comment: Но они не имеют класса, мне нужно, чтобы применение шло безклассовым ссылкам.

Comment: Представьте не CSS код, а HTML-код вашей структуры.

Comment: Точной структуры нет, ссылки разбросаны по всей странице.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос исчерпан, я нашел решение, нужное, которое я просил:

```
a:not([class]){
   -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
   transition: all 300ms linear;
}
```

таким макаром я получаю анимацию и стилизацию ссылок без класса!

Answer (score 0):

[Псевдоселекторы](http://goldblog.com.ua/2009/09/selektor-css/), но можно использовать DOM-пути к ссылкам, к примеру:

```
  <div class="divclass">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </div>
```

Тогда CSS:

```
  .divclass a {
    // стиль, применяемый к ссылке
  }
```

Comment: Сударь, вы издеваетесь?

Comment: У меня на сайте тысячи ссылок и вы предлагаете, чтоб я таким методом решил?

Comment: В первую очередь я предлагаю адекватную верстку. Если их тысяча - их  можно проклассифицировать, задав классы либо родительским элементам, либо им самим.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать [селекторы атрибутов](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov).

Comment: Не то, мне нужно исключаещее свойство.

Comment: те всех классов без их перечисления

Answer (score 0):

Изначально код написан неверно, никто не делит свойства, например, тэга `<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>` на столько частей, в данном случае их три, тем более стиль общий. Если вы хотите задать стиль, например, всем тэгам `<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>`, которые у вас есть на странице и у которых нет класса, то задавайте прям в CSS таким образом:

```
a { и тут пишется стиль для тега весь стиль не нужно делить его}
a:hover { что будет при наведении }
```

Т.е. те ссылки, у которых нет класса, они по умолчанию будут наследовать стиль, который прописан в css для тэга a { и тут пишется стиль для тега}.